# Borderlines for GDPR related questions

Tags: discussion

The *General Data Protection Regulation* (GDPR) affects everyone working in the field, since it extends even beyond the EU. It's a hot topic, and all kind of [myths](http://privacylawblog.fieldfisher.com/2016/what-you-think-you-know-about-the-gdpr-and-why-you-may-be-wrong) and claims are developing around it. Naturally it produces questions on related StackExchange sites like Server Fault and [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), some possibly too technical to be answered on the [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

What is on-topic here? Where should we draw the line between *technical* and *legal* questions? I think it's obvious that questions asking *how* to perform an exact action to comply with the GDPR are on-topic, while questions seeking merely *interpretation of the regulation* are clearly off-topic.

Then there's gray area of questions related on the measurements, actions and perspectives other professionals involved in (technical) processing of personal data have taken. Any thoughts on how should we handle those? While there is a risk that we try to give too definite answers to questions no one yet actually knows about, we may also reject good questions if we are too critical.

Answer (score 9):

I think we should create a canonical question/answer about GPDR. For me it's more a legal issue, like SOX404.

The problem I see is, yes we can give generic advice for public facing site (which we can cover in our canonical answer) but in the end only an auditor or a lawyer can correctly answer the OP.

I state that opinion as with GDPR, I don't think, on a online platform like there, that we can go deep in the discussion with the OP to know if he follow GPDR. (an example; how their HR handle employees record from USA<->EU, etc..)

Comment: Canonical GDPR question regarding _how to comply_ & _is it allowed to X_ would be great. I might even ask & self answer one, if I've got some time. Then there's purely technical questions that should be allowed: _to comply GDPR I'll X, is it efficient if I Y_ or _....but I can't get Z working_, where the answer doesn't interpret the regulation, but helps with some actual implementation.

Comment: In my view, the canonical answer should be like the software licensing one, explaining why we can't really help in most cases. I agree with @EsaJokinen about the "help with actual implementation" part.

Comment: Ok, here's something to start with: [Can you help me with my GDPR issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/908181/can-you-help-me-with-my-gdpr-issue/908182)